# Setting up a cookie for a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, css, joomla

i managed to change the background image of my Joomla site with jQuery. Now i try to find out how to set a cookie for it. Please help!

Following my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery("#change-bg-to-1").click(function() {

        jQuery("body").removeClass("bg-2");
        jQuery("body").addClass("bg-1");

  });

   jQuery("#change-bg-to-2").click(function() {

        jQuery("body").removeClass("bg-1");
        jQuery("body").addClass("bg-2");

});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store it in localStorage:

```
//save a value to localStorage
localStorage.myClass = 'bg-1';
```

-

```
//retrieve the value from localStorage
jQuery("body").addClass(localStorage.myClass);
```

Comment: Thanks. Better idea! so where to add your code?

Comment: @user3138179 wherever you want to use it..

Comment: Yes. But here in my code? In case of two images.

Comment: @user3138179 It depends on what you want to do. If you can't understand this basic level of code, what you're doing is too advanced for you and you should study the very basics of javascript.

Comment: Just trying to learn.. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user3138179 and I'm trying to help you. How are you learning if I write all of the code for you? I showed you how to save and retrieve a value with localStorage. What is your question? I'd be glad to answer questions. That's what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Trying to figure it out.